# How to calculate vertices of dodecahedron using W|A?

Tags: polyhedra, wolfram-alpha

Can I calculate for example with wolfram alpha coordinates of vertices of dodecahedron?
I know coordinates of center point of dodecahedron (center of gravity) and the height of dodecahedron.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron#Cartesian_coordinates

Comment: Of course that's just one possibility.  You can then take an arbitrary rotation, and appropriate translation and scaling (assuming your dodecahedron is a regular one).

Comment: There is an extensive discussion on the building of a dodecahedron and its vertices at this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632936/cleverest-construction-of-a-dodecahedron-icosahedron/1566268#1566268  StackExchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Wolfram Alpha can do it. Inputting [`PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolyhedronData%5B%22Dodecahedron%22%2C+%22VertexCoordinates%22%5D) into Wolfram Alpha will yield a set of vertex coordinates you can use for a dodecahedron with unit edge length. Alternatively, [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dodecahedron.html) gives a simple set of coordinates for a dodecahedron with edge length $\dfrac2{\phi}$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio: $(0,\pm\phi^{-1},\pm\phi),(\pm\phi^{-1},\pm\phi,0),(\pm\phi,0,\pm\phi^{-1}),(\pm 1,\pm 1,\pm 1)$ and all combinations of signs are taken.